# Redirecting to a custom error page when a authorization policy fails

Tags: asp.net-core

I have created a authorization policy and registered the handler in the startup.cs file. I would like to redirect the user to a custom error page when the policy fails, but always get redirected to /Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=MyPage. I cannot seem to figure out how to register a custom error page. I have tried a few options like having app.UseStatusCodePages. Any help is greatly appreciated
StartUp. Cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.AddAuthorization(options =>
               {

                   options.AddPolicy("HomePolicyTestPolicy", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new AuthorizedPermissionsRequirement(new List<UserPermissionsEnum>() { UserPermissionsEnum.ADEAdmin })));
               });
                services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, AuthorizedPermissionsHandler>();

            }

            // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
            {
                if (env.IsLocalOrDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                    // app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                }
                else
                {
                    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                    app.UseHsts();
                }

                app.UseStaticFiles();
                app.UseAuthentication();
                app.UseSession();

                app.UseStatusCodePages(async context =>
                {
                    if (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 403)
                    {
                        context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Error/Index");
                    }
                });


            }
Handler:

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, AuthorizedPermissionsRequirement requirement)
            {
                context.Fail();

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
Controller:

     [Authorize(Policy = "HomePolicyTestPolicy")]
            public IActionResult PolicyTest()
            {
                return View();
            }
```

Result: It always redirects me to /Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=PolicyTest. I cannot figure out to let it redirect to Home/Error.

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the relevant contents of the Startup.cs

Comment: @ShahzadHassan Please see the code above. Thank You

Comment: You need to move the call to `UseStatusCodePages` up before the `UseStaticFiles`. The order is important, otherwise, your middleware will not get a response after 403 is generated.

Comment: I tried that too, when it gets to the usestatuscode middle ware it is already having a 404 not found on  /Account/AccessDenied.

Comment: Can you please upload the sample code to GitHub? I think there is something wrong going on at your end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the status code page middleware, check out [handle errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configuring-status-code-pages)

```
app.UseStatusCodePages(async context => {
  if (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 403)
  {
     // redirect to page
  }
});
```

Comment: Hello Zach, I tried doing that but could get it to work. I have updated question with the code. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is don't use context.Fail(), instead do this:

replace:

```
context.Fail();
```

with:

```
var mvcContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;
mvcContext.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("MyAction", "MyController", null);
context.Succeed(requirement);
```

allowing the context to succeed, will execute the context, which is now a redirect.